# Update asks for authentication

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

When I try to update I get a message that some of the updates need authentication sources. The updates shown are Ubuntu base and NVIDIA X server setting. I don't know how to import the key to the authentication table in the setting.

I use the update application so I just press the install now. Then I get this message:

```
Los paquetes a instalar necesarios de fuentes no autenticadas.
```

(since I use the Spanish version: it seems to mean the packages to be installed need sources that are not authenticated).

[image]

Comment: post the command you ran and the message.

Comment: This is fine. It just wants to confirm you know you are getting update from  a source which is not from Ubuntu. Accept it if you know the souce.

Comment: The thing is, when I accept it doesn't do anything. The update program closes without updating.

Comment: Have you tried terminal? Open Terminal, and use this command `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  give us the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means your source of update has invalid certificate or certificate may be expired recently. in order to ignore that message, don't update your software when automatic pop-up shows. do it manually. in that no such message will be shown. i hope this will helps you.